# Lost Reputation for Question I Didn't Ask

Tags: support, reputation

I logged into SO today for the first time in a few days.  I noticed that I lost some reputation, so when I checked my account, I see that I lost 20 reputation for asking a question titled "I feel a bit lost with programming".

I never asked this question and the login system shows I didn't even login that day (yesterday).  The question was deleted, so I cannot even see any more information about it or when it was posted.  The pic below is a grab from my account screen.

Is this a bug, or did someone login to my account?

[image]

Comment: You are a bit confused, that was not a question you asked, it was an answer you posted to a question asked by a user named Jake.  It had the [career-development] tag, a tag that's actively being hunted and getting exterminated by the SO moderators right now.  You lost the rep on your "Working on an actual project will go a long way" answer.  Another way to interpret that deletion is SO trying to get rid of the Doh factor.  Nothing personal.

Comment: Thanks so much for the quick response.  I was confused, but it makes sense somewhat now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That is probably not the reputation you lost for a question you asked, but the reputation you lost after a question you answered has been deleted. As your answer got 2 up-votes, you lost 20 points when the question has been delete.

Since the past days, such events are immediately reported in the reputation page to keep your reputation updated.